# How to execute code inside of a container using Github Actions

Tags: github-actions

How to execute code inside of a container using Github Actions.

This is what I tried:

```
  run-integration-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: http://image.com:latest
    steps:
        run: |
          node index.js
```

Error

```
index.js': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

index.js lives inside of the docker container. How do I run it?

Comment: Is the `index.js` a file from the repo? If yes, you may need to add the `actions/checkout` action before executing the `node` command.

Comment: @GuiFalourd It is in the repo inside of a folder. It gets containerized.

Comment: How do you currently checkout the repo inside the container?